# ArgumentError: Factory not registered: user - Hartl Chapter 7.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble getting the test to pass in Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial [Chapter 7.1.3](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec-tests_with_factories).

### Here is the error message:

> ```
> Failures:
>
>   1) User pages profile page 
>      Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
>      ArgumentError:
>        Factory not registered: user
>      # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
>      # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
>
>   2) User pages profile page 
>      Failure/Error: let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
>      ArgumentError:
>        Factory not registered: user
>      # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:8:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
>      # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:9:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
>
> Finished in 2.72 seconds
> 37 examples, 2 failures
>
> Failed examples:
>
> rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:11 # User pages profile page 
> rspec ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12 # User pages profile page
> ```

### This is my user_pages_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: user.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign up') }
  end
end
```

### This is my factories.rb:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name     "Michael Hartl"
    email    "mhartl@example.com"
    password "foobar"
    password_confirmation "foobar"
  end
end
```

### And this is the `Gemfile`:

```
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.2.1', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', '0.7.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.4.0'
end
```

I've tried rebooting the server, and running `bundle exec rake db:reset`, `db:test:prepare`, `db:test:load`, `db:migrate` - nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Is your factories.rb file located at spec/factories.rb?

Answer (score 2):

If you are following Michael Hartl's guide, it is possible that you may be using `spork` and `guard` too. Updates in factories are not noted by spork, unless spork is restarted.

If you are using them, try restarting `spork` and `guard`